# Ruby saying file doesnt exist

Tags: ruby, macos, file, file-io

I'm new to Ruby, and I am writing a test program just to get some of the features down. Here is the program

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class FileManager
  def read_file(filename)
    return nil unless File.exist?(filename)
    File.read(filename)
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  fm = FileManager.new
  puts "What file would you like to open?"
  fname = gets

  puts fm.read_file fname
end
```

As you can see, it is very simple. If I comment the first line of the `read_file` method, I get this error

```
No such file or directory - /Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/Ruby\ Test/text (Errno::ENOENT)
from /Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Ruby Test/ruby.rb:6:in `read_file'
from /Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Ruby Test/ruby.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

when I run the program and use this file: `/Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/Ruby\ Test/text`

However, if I run `cat /Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/Ruby\ Test/text`, it outputs `Hello, world!`, as it should.

I don't believe it's a permissions issue because I own the folder, but just in case I've tried running the program as root. Also, I have made sure that `fname` is the actual name of the file, not nil. I've tried both escaped and unescaped versions of the path, along with just `text` or the full path. I know for a fact the file exists, so why is Ruby giving me this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gets filename` the filename includes a newline `\n`.

You have to remove it in your filename:

```
gets filename 
p filename        #"test.rb\n"
p File.exist?(filename) #false
p File.exist?(filename.chomp) #true
```

(And you don't need to mask the spaces)

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're shell-escaping your spaces even though `gets` does not go through a shell. You want to enter "/Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Ruby Test/text" instead of "/Users/macuser/Projects/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/Ruby\ Test/text".

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried unescaped paths too. Neither one seems to work.